# Laravel pivot table (Retreive all items that belongs to)

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Item table that contains fields
I have a template table that groups the fields with a pivot table
I have a page table that contains the template being used

I need to retrieve the field list associated with the template being used by the page

```
    $gestionPage->load('template', 'parent');
    $page = $gestionPage->get()[0];
    $formulaire = Item::find($page->template_id)->with('itemsTemplate')->get();

    foreach($formulaire as $k=>$v){
        $data[] = $v->nom;
    }
    dd($data);
```

So fare, $data contain all fields (Not just the one that belongs to the right template)

```
   array:3 [▼
     0 => "Titre"
     1 => "Texte"
     2 => "wysiwyg"
   ]
```

2 => "wysiwyg" is not part of the template ...

It should output

```
   array:2 [▼
     0 => "Titre"
     1 => "Texte"
   ]
```

I don't understand how the pivot systeme works ...

In the item model

```
public function itemsTemplate()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Template::class);
}
```

In the item model

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
}
```

How to easaly retreive the list of items a template id owns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here:

```
public function templates() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Template::class)->withPivot(array $fields);
}

public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->withPivot(array $fields)
}
```

then you can access the pivot table fields like this here:
$item->pivot->field

Comment: Thanks! return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->withPivot(array('template_id', 'item_id')); did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code. See if it works now. Read how many to many relationships works in Laravel from this link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```html
$gestionPage->load('template', 'parent');
$page = $gestionPage->get()[0];

$formulaire = Item::find($page->template_id)->templates()->get();

dd($formulaire);

//Rename this from itemsTemplate to templates - just because is plural

public function templates() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Template::class);
}

public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
}
```